# Hard drive issues after setting to offline and disconnecting the hard drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, diskpart, disk-management

I used Disk Management to set my hard drive to offline ([method](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/disk-set-as-offline-or-online.53106/)). I shut my computer off then disconnected the SATA cable and PSU cable from the hard drive. I rebooted and used my computer for a few hours. I shut down and plugged the cables back in. My computer will not get past this [screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUvloQ-f6Ac) now. It just spins the circle forever. The automatic start up repair did not fix it. If I disconnect my hard drive, my computer boots as normal. At this point, I reset my CMOS battery and BIOS. The HDD was detected in the BIOS. I plugged in a USB with Windows 10 installation and tried to launch the recovery tools but they would not load after an hour. If I shutdown and disconnect my hard drive, it loads instantly. My motherboard supports hot plug, so I enabled that setting in the BIOS. I disconnected my hard drive and booted into Windows as normal. I plugged in my hard drive then I tried launching Disk Management and Diskpart in CMD. They were unable to load and were just stuck for 30 minutes. The moment I disconnected my hard drive Disk Management and Diskpart loads instantly. I reconnect my hard drive and the same issue occurs.

Edit
I forgot to mention that I installed this driver when I was using my computer for 3 hours. https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29988/Intel-Graphics-Windows-10-DCH-Drivers

While trying to fix my hard drive problem, I created another problem that will not let me boot into Windows. I get the stop code critical process died error. The last thing I did was perform a system restore to a point 3 days ago.

Windows version: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit 20H2

Motherboard: Asus z270-AR

Hard drive: Seagate ST2000DM006 2TB BarraCuda 3.5" 7200RPM SATA3 Desktop Hard Drive (2 years old)

SSD: Samsung 960 EVO (my boot drive)

Comment: Are you able to start in Safe Mode (with Networking)? Hold down the Shift Key and start with the power button.  If you make a bootable Windows 10 ISO (Media Creation Link), can you run a Repair Install. Windows is not running so this may not work.

Comment: Try plugging the drive into a different computer running Windows, to see if you can bring it back "online". Or into a machine running Linux and use the fdisk command to change the Disk ID.

Comment: Sounds like the HDD isn’t functional. HDD I/O is known to cause slow boot times and other weird behavior

Comment: Did you try re-seating the SATA/power cables on the drive & motherboard? If so, try a  known-good cable, such as that from your SSD, booting from the Windows install USB. If still not working, verify S.M.A.R.T data by booting a Linux Live USB [e.g. Ubuntu install USB], install `smartmontools` & issue the following: `sudo smartctl -a /dev/<disk> sudo smartctl -t short /dev/<disk>; sleep 61; sudo smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` and review the test status. It doesn't seem likely the HDD would fail if it was just working, and it doesn't need to be offlined in order to be disconnected if using shutdown.

Comment: It seems the HDD somehow died and the BIOS is no longer detecting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my hard drive was completely fine. I had 2 hard drives in my computer. My current one is fine. My dead one was left there for years unplugged. I completely forgot about it and was actually plugging in my dead hard drive instead of working one.